# Display a single country with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, vector

Can I display a single country using Openlayers?

I'm not trying to restrict zoom levels or . I want only one single country to be displayed. The rest of the world cannot be displayed.

My reasearch shows no information on my specific issue.

Comment: Yes, this is easily done. What format is your data in?

Comment: I do not have any data to use or data format so far.

I was just researching the various alternatives to mapping in Javascript and found only full maps without instructions on how to break them

The objective is to make informational maps by country, continent and worldwide