# Shows Netherlands region on map on every zoom level not other region in Open Street Maps

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

I want to show/display only Netherland region on Openstreet map, dont want to show other region on maps. Same thing apply for zoom in or zoom out also.
I have tried with applying bounds but does not work,when user decrease the zoom level it shows the whole world map.

Can you please help me or guide me in that.
Waiting for your response.

Comment: This question was asked at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52596/display-a-single-country-with-openlayers - it doesn't have an answer, but perhaps you could look at the additional information that was requested on that question, and consider updating your question with some more details. For example, are you generating the OSM tiles yourself (e.g. from a local tileserver)?

Comment: If you render your own tiles you could just do an import of the netherlands dump file from http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/netherlands.html instead of the full planet dump.